# pom.xml is unable to find the jar

Tags: pom.xml, build.xml

I am a newbie for maven and trying to convert an ant project to maven project. I am trying to acheive the same as in build.xml. I have build.xml that create 2 jar files and one war file which is bundled into one ear file. I have the tags in build.xml as below

```
<target name="indweb" depends="ejbjar, compileWeb">
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/indweb.war" manifest="${webDir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
        <fileset dir="${webDir}/" excludes="**/ind-help/** , **/ind-info/**">
            <exclude name="${webDir}/WEB-INF/lib/ind_ejb.jar"/>
            <exclude name="${webDir}/WEB-INF/lib/ind_utilities.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </jar>
</target>
-----------------------

<target name="ejbjar" depends="ind_utilities">
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/ind_ejb.jar" manifest="${ejbSourceDir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
        <fileset dir="${ejbCompileDir}">
            <include name="com/**/module/*.class"/>
            <include name="com/**/packet/*.class"/>
            <include name="com/**/mbean/*.class"/>
        </fileset>
        <metainf dir="${ejbSourceDir}/META-INF">
            <include name="*.xml"/>
        </metainf>
    </jar>
</target>         
---------

<target name="ind_utilities" depends="compileEjb">
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/ind_utilities.jar">
        <fileset dir="${ejbCompileDir}">
            <include name="com/pkg/ind/lib/**/*.class"/>
            <include name="com/pkg/ind/security/*.class"/>
            <include name="com/pkg/ind/audit/*.class"/>
        </fileset>
    </jar>
</target>
----------------

<target name="compileEjb">
        <echo message="Compiling ejb source codes in ${ejbSourceDir} ..."/>
        <javac destdir="${ejbCompileDir}" srcdir="${ejbSourceDir}" classpathref="master-classpath" target="1.6"
               debug="${Compiler.Debug}" failonerror="true" executable="${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac"/>
    </target>
---------------------

<target name="compileWeb">
        <echo message="Compiling ind web source codes in ${webSourceDir} ..."/>
        <javac destdir="${webDir}/WEB-INF/classes" srcdir="${webSourceDir}" classpathref="master-classpath" target="1.6"
               debug="${Compiler.Debug}" failonerror="true" executable="${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac"/>
    </target>
```

Can anyone help me how to acheive this pom.xml.

Comment: So... what did you try?  What jar could it not find?

Comment: I am getting this error while trying to executing pom.xml

BaseAction.java:[58,20] package javax.servlet does not exist
BaseAction.java:[59,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
BaseAction.java:[63,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist
BaseAction.java:[67,35] package org.apache.commons.beanutils does not exist
BaseAction.java:[68,35] package org.apache.commons.beanutils does not exist
BaseAction.java:[69,16] package javax.ejb does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dependencies to your pom for struts, beanutils, Java EE, and whatever else you're dependent on.

Some of these may depend on others - e.g., struts probably pulls in Java EE somehow.  In these cases, you need to be careful about version conflicts if you explicitly also depend on Java EE and specify a different version.

Or... I'm assuming you know a lot less than you do, the dependencies are all there, and the problem is something else entirely!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response here. I did add the dependencies in the pom.xml and it worked.